# Recognize and count spec. characters

Tags: javascript, loops, replace

The goal of this code is to figure out deletions requred
to leave the string with no equal characters following each other.

> ababa = 0  abaaab = 2  and  aaaa = 3

```
var input ="abababaaaabaaab";
var sringl = input.length;
    // input.substr(input.length)
var pos=0;
var pos2=1;

var output =0;    
while (pos < sringl) {
    console.log (input.substr(pos,1), input.substr(pos2,1));
    if (input.substr(pos,1) === input.substr(pos2,1)){
        input = input.replace(input.substr(pos2,1),"");
        --sringl
        ++output
       // ++pos
    }
    else {++pos;++pos2} console.log (output,sringl,input);
}
```

The console log is to show me what it does.
The result in the var

```
output
```

is right. Could yout tell me what the issue with the attempt toreplace?

Comment: If the `output` is right, what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: the replace does this "bbbaabaaab" instead of  this "ababababab".

Comment: If regex is allowed then `input = input.replace( /(\w)(\1+)/g, '$1' );`

Comment: I provided a simple solution, I hope it helps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with the code is that the replace will remove the first occurance of the character, not the occurance at `pos2`. If you use the character position to remove the character instead of a replace, it will work:

```
input = input.substr(0, pos2) + input.substr(pos2 + 1);
```

You can simplify the code to use only one variable for position, and read the string length property instead of maintaining a variable for it:

```js
var input ="abababaaaabaaab";

var output = 0;
var pos = 1;
while (pos < input.length) {
  if (input.charAt(pos - 1) === input.charAt(pos)){
    input = input.substr(0, pos) + input.substr(pos + 1);
    output++;
  } else {
    pos++;
  }
}

document.write(output + ' ' + input);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, as I am ( at ~ hour 12 of) learning JS, I didn't know the charAt Method (don't even know the difference between statements and methods). Could you please clearify the issue with replace.

Comment: @Rich: The replace method doesn't know that you have got the character from a position in the string and wanted to replace that specific character, it only sees that you want to replace `"a"` with `""`. It will replace the first `a` that it finds in the string.

Comment: I see. And i thought it would  replace the a the poition.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like the following one:

```
var input = "abababaaaabaaab";

alert(RemoveDuplicateCharacters(input));
```

The function looks like this:

```
function RemoveDuplicateCharacters(input) {
    // Handle empty input data
    if (input.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    var currentPosition = 1;
    var result = input[0];

    while (currentPosition < input.length) {
        if (input[currentPosition - 1] != input[currentPosition]) {
            result = result + input[currentPosition];
        }

        currentPosition++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In my opinion it shows a possible solution to the question itself - so it does.